# Xamarin.IOS dismissing UIViewController

Tags: xamarin.ios

Good day friends,

I have a web application I have wrapped in a web view. In that application, I have a screen where a user can print a PDF document. My issue is whenever the user prints the PDF and dismisses the modal where the PDF was shown, they are logged out of the application.

Here is My code for displaying the modal:
[image]

```
public void OpenPdf(string pdfStr)
{
    var documentpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    var localfilename = Path.GetFileName("document.pdf");
    var localpath = Path.Combine(documentpath, localfilename);

    if (File.Exists(localpath))
    {
           File.Delete(localpath);
    }

    var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(pdfStr);
    var stream = new FileStream(localpath, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write);
    var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);
    writer.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    writer.Close();

    var qlpreview = new PreviewController
    {
         DataSource = new PreviewDatasource(NSUrl.FromFilename(localpath), localfilename)
    };

    PresentViewController(qlpreview, true, null);
}
```

How do I make the user successfully dismiss the modal without logging them out of the application?

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: please do NOT post code as an image!!

Comment: Thanks. I have updated it with textual code.

Comment: What code is used to dismiss the PreviewController?

Comment: @pnavk, there is no specific code used to dismiss it. The OS seems to take care of that. However, that PresentViewController method's 3rd parameter is an action that is called when the controller is dismissed.

Comment: Hi, do you mean want to open pdf file inside the application? If so, you could use wkwebview to open it.

Comment: Hi @JuniorJiang-MSFT. I tried using the WkWebView as per this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/webview. However, the issue is there is no way to print the doc or to go back to the previous page, even after adding AllowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true. Any thoughts?

Comment: @mapussah If need to print pdf, how about using [AirPrint](https://developer.apple.com/airprint/)?